# Can you name this audio compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, audio, compression

Hello stack exchangers!
I have a quick question about audio compression.
I was just thinking (I know hardly any about this subject)
is it possible to compress audio by slicing the track into small pieces (Larger than the individual vibrations of course) and classify those pieces by a frequency and a volume value (You could compress this as well)
I wanted to learn more about this but was unable to find something about it online, where most articles talked about dynamic range compression. 
I know it must exist but possibly because it is a bad method for audio compression or something I have been unable to put a name to it. 
So my question is if any of you know what this process might be called!
Thank you very much, and have a nice day!

Comment: This should be of interest... https://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python/

Comment: You may know that except in very special rare cases, an *audio* is never reducible to a single frequency/volume value... Even if you slice it... If you want to work with the frequencies you have to use the Fourier transform to get the spectral function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to account for the fact that there can be more than one important frequency present at any time.  If you do then this is how pretty much every lossy audio codec like mp3, aac, ogg, etc. works:

1. Divide the sound into short bits (I think the common ones are all between 512 and 2500 samples)
2. Separate each short bit into distinct frequencies
3. Discard the frequencies that are inaudible, because there is no sound at that frequency or because of perceptual masking
4. Encode the volume of the remaining frequencies in a compressed format, with an accuracy that depends on how easily you could hear the difference in different volumes.

This technique is generally called "perceptual audio coding".

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you are intuiting what is known as the [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT).

If you are serious about learning more, a free resource that does a good job of teaching how this works is Steve Smith's "[The Scientists and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](https://dspguide.com/)".